# Как убрать пунктир в подменю

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import*
root=Tk()
m=Menu(root)
m2=Menu(m)
m.add_cascade(label='list',menu=m2)
m2.add_command(label='command')
root.config(menu=m)
```

[image]

Как мне избавиться от "--------" в подменю m2?

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте:

```
m2 = Menu(m, tearoff=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()

m = Menu(root)
m2 = Menu(m, tearoff = False)
m.add_cascade(label = 'list', menu = m2)
m2.add_command(label = 'command')
root.config(menu = m)

root.mainloop()
```